# Question> Does changing "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" to "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" causes problem to plugins?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, distriqt

I've been using AS3/Anes/Distriqt.

Does changing "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" to "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" causes problem?

will anesdistriqt such as messaging, etc., malfunction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication` for all your applications now. distriqt's extensions no longer support the older `android.support.xxx` libraries and you should upgrade to `androidx`.